# How do I create a .dmg image from a dvd on linux?

Tags: linux, mac, virtualbox, linux-mint

Can I type `dd if=/dev/sr0 of=name.dmg` and the output will work on MacOS or is it more complicated?
What I have already tried is to create a dmg file with gnome-disks which normally creates iso files but I changed the output to .dmg which wouldn't work since I couldn't load the file in the VirtualBox.
I am using Linux Mint Version 18

Comment: You can dump a DVD into a .iso file just like you have described and mount it virtually.

Comment: My goal is to create a dmg file from MacOS dvd to run it in the virtualbox lik disk utility on mac

Comment: Does the iso file work just as good as the dmg with iBoot

Comment: It does work with apple disk image I tried it before

Comment: Is this a Mac OS Installation CD?

Comment: Yes it is I bought it for 30 €

Comment: There is a tuto here http://www.garrettcpa.net/dokuwiki/doku.php?id=linux:dmg

Comment: not any more :(